# dead.letter file warns me about uncorrectable sectors I can't find

Tags: command-line, fedora, logs, hard-disk

I have seen separate answers for all the little pieces of my question, I looked really hard, but it still doesn't seem to make any sense. A little history of how this happened.

- Yesterday by using randomly using `ls` in my root directory as root, I discover a file called `dead.letter`.
- Said file contains warnings that seem pretty ominous:

  ```
  Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 8 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
  Device: /dev/sda [SAT], 8 Offline uncorrectable sectors
  ```

  Those two warnings repeat for a final file size of `53346` (bytes, I guess? This is what the `ls` command said).
- I check online, search engines inform me that my hard drive is dying. OK, good, *I know what's going on*.
- Except that I checked my hard drive's health two weeks ago and it was fine, and when I check it now through `smartctl -H /dev/sda` it tells me overall health is good.
- Even weirder, why is it in a `dead.letter` file? From what I understand it's a file that happens when you abort a mail you're currently writing, so wtf?
- The `dead.letter` file, says the `stat` command, has not been modified since January 18th. Was this a one-time event?

**So here's my question: is my hard drive fine or is it dying in a really sneaky way?** *I have no idea what's going on.*

I run a Fedora 24/Gnome Shell on a 2012 Asus U36SG. Filesystem is all ext4 on LVM2… I think. I hope this is enough information!

Comment: Was the file created by a cron job that checks the drive's status but failed to send a local mail, maybe?

Comment: to be sure, boot on a rescue/install CD and fsck filesystem on sda. (fsck all file system migt be a lengthy but safe solution)

Comment: To follow on from roaima's answer, read up on smartctl and how to interpret the attributes. If the disk is not an SSD you can run weekly `smartctl -t short /dev/sda` or `-t long` tests to check all blocks are readable. The results are in `-a` output.

Comment: Thank you all, I cannot attempt better tests for the time being due to time and material constraints so I will accept roaima 's answer as it answered my main question, which was more about general understanding than specific testing. I will keep in mind `fsck` and advice on `smartctl` usage, though. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dead.letter` file is created by mail clients when they cannot send email. It's likely you don't have any mail subsystem installed on your machine. The date of the file corresponds to the date the mail was attempted.

On 18th January it looks like `smartctl` tried to warn you of 8 sectors that couldn't be read. This is a warning sign that the disk *may* be dying but it's not a definite marker. I'd start saving for a replacement, though.

You confirmed that the disk has been more recently checked and was reported to be fine. What's happened here is that you wrote new data to those sectors, the disk failed to write them, and silently remapped them to dedicated spare sectors elsewhere on the disk.

Three are now no outstanding faulty sectors.

As the disk gets older and more sectors need remapping, eventually the spares will get filled up and real data will be lost. It's just a matter of time. Ensure you have got backups - or that you can afford to lose any or all of your data either in one big go out subtly so you don't really notice the corruption at first.